# Extracting a Piece of Text from a String -- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using `document.getElementById` to get the `innerHTML` from a `<div>`.  It will return something like this...

`<span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #545454;">Unit 1, Lesson 2: Ordering Large Numbers</span>`

I want to extract the "Unit 1, Lesson 2" part from that string using Javascript.  It won't always be "Unit 1, Lesson 2" though.  It could be "Unit 10, Lesson 8" so using `substring()` seems to be out.

**Desired Outcome...**

`<span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #545454;">Unit 1, Lesson 5: Ordering Large Numbers</span>` should yield "Unit 1, Lesson 5"

`<span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #545454;">Unit 11, Lesson 28: Ordering Large Numbers</span>` should yield "Unit 11, Lesson 28"

I'm not good at all with Javascript, so if I'm missing a simple function to do this, please let me know what it is.

**Edit: Alternatively, if there's a way to cut off everything after the ":", I could work with that as well.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use textContent which would return only text without html.

So if you have element:

`<span id="test"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #545454;">Unit 1, Lesson 2: Ordering Large Numbers</span></span>`

You can get it's 'Unit 1, Lesson 2' part like this:

```
document.getElementById('test').textContent.split(":")[0];
```

Comment: I like the looks of this, but I'm getting "TypeError: document.getElementById(...).innerText is undefined" when I try it.

Comment: right, innerText might not work for firefox, use textContent instead. I updated the answer

Comment: We have a winner!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's regex pattern match function:

```
var pattern = /.*(Unit \d+, Lesson \d+):/
var el = document.getElement....innerHTML
var match = pattern.match(el)[1];
alert(match)
```